# Webfont license by page views

Tags: webfonts

I'm looking into using [this font](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mostardesign/sofia-pro/) from myfonts.com on a website. When you purchase a font from them for use on the web, you are purchasing a one-time license for a certain number of page views per month.

This license is described in more detail here:

https://www.myfonts.com/licensing/webfont/

How would myfonts.com know if I am exceeding my license? If the font is self-hosted, how do they know how many page views I'm getting? Is this some sort of honor-system or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer from myfonts.com support:

> Webfont licensing is explained here:
>   https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/museo/licensing.html
>
> In the supplied webfont kit that's self hosted, there is CSS. The CSS
>   includes and @import rule. When its url is read by the browser, it
>   calls our server, and a pageview is counted.